# Book about a group of kids that were cloned from criminals

Tags: story-identification, clones, biology

I remember, as a kid, reading a book about a group of kids, who were cloned from tissue samples taken from violent criminals. I am pretty sure that all of the adults are in on it, if not most. It was on an experiment to see if violence was genetic, or not.

The kids were raised in a dystopian, knowledge-restricted town. I remember that if the clones went beyond the border, they would get violently sick. I also remember that, in the town, not all of the kids are clones, just a few.

I am pretty sure that the narration switches between several of the main characters. I also think that one of the kid's "dad" is one of the scientists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [*Masterminds*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22249695-masterminds) by Gordon Korman.

> Eli Frieden has never left Serenity, New Mexico...why would he ever
> want to? Then one day, he bikes to the edge of the city limits and
> something so crazy and unexpected happens, it changes everything.
>
> Eli convinces his friends to help him investigate further, and soon it
> becomes clear that nothing is as it seems in Serenity. The clues mount
> to reveal a shocking discovery, connecting their ideal crime-free
> community to some of the greatest criminal masterminds ever known.
>
> The kids realize they can trust no one—least of all their own parents.

[image]

Comment: Note the blurb for [book #2 in the series](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25741007-criminal-destiny) which is kind of a spoiler; *"What they discover will change everything, leading them straight into the Plastic Works and the heart of the experiment, **in order to uncover the deadly criminals they’re cloned from** —and any evidence that will convince the outside world to believe the truth.*"